# Mac OS Kernel Panic

Tags: catalina, crash, kernel-panic

My mac keeps restarting on sleep. It's the latest 16' model

Below is the report:

````
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffffa3f7efbb40 : 0xffffff80121215cd 
0xffffffa3f7efbb90 : 0xffffff801225a3c5 
0xffffffa3f7efbbd0 : 0xffffff801224bf7e 
0xffffffa3f7efbc20 : 0xffffff80120c7a40 
0xffffffa3f7efbc40 : 0xffffff8012120c97 
0xffffffa3f7efbd40 : 0xffffff8012121087 
0xffffffa3f7efbd90 : 0xffffff80128c2c7c 
0xffffffa3f7efbe00 : 0xffffff8012816487 
0xffffffa3f7efbe50 : 0xffffff8012815d69 
0xffffffa3f7efbe60 : 0xffffff801282d2fe 
0xffffffa3f7efbea0 : 0xffffff8012814b18 
0xffffffa3f7efbec0 : 0xffffff8012163545 
0xffffffa3f7efbf40 : 0xffffff8012163071 
0xffffffa3f7efbfa0 : 0xffffff80120c713e 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task
Boot args: chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev

Mac OS version:
19E266

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.4.0: Wed Mar  4 22:28:40 PST 2020; root:xnu-6153.101.6~15/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: AB0AA7EE-3D03-3C21-91AD-5719D79D7AF6
Kernel slide:     0x0000000011e00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8012000000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8011f00000
System model name: MacBookPro16,1 (Mac-E1008331FDC96864)
System shutdown begun: NO

System uptime in nanoseconds: 15929667814326
last loaded kext at 162118321994: >!UAudio  322.2 (addr 0xffffff7f9945e000, size 434176)
loaded kexts:
com.getdropbox.dropbox.kext 1.10.3
com.google.drivefs.filesystems.dfsfuse  37.0.8
com.kairos.driver.DuetDisplay   1
@filesystems.cd9660 1.4.4
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000    3.0.8
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   3.0.8
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 5.1.16
@fileutil   20.036.15
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   5.1.16
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.4f6
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>pmtelemetry    1
>AGPM   111.4.4
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>AGDCBacklightControl   5.1.16
>!A!IKBLGraphics    14.0.5
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>BridgeAudioCommunication   6.70.3
>!ABacklight    180.3
>ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.4
>!AFIVRDriver   4.1.0
>!AAVEBridge    6.1
>!AMCCSControl  1.11
>!AMuxControl2  5.1.16
>!ABridgeAudio!C    6.70.3
>!AGFXHDA   100.1.426
>!AHIDALSService    1
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3430.1
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>!A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.5
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>usb.!UHostBillboardDevice  1.0
|SCSITaskUserClient 422.101.1
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe  1
>!AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.100.5
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.apfs   1412.101.1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
>!UAudio    322.2
@kext.AMDRadeonX6100HWLibs  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000HWServices  3.0.8
|IOAVB!F    840.3
>!ASSE  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000Framebuffer 3.0.8
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
@!AGPUWrangler  5.1.16
>IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
@kext.AMDSupport    3.0.8
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
>!AGraphicsControl  5.1.16
|IONDRVSupport  575.1
>!AActuatorDriver   3440.1
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
>!AHS!BDriver   3430.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.4f6
>!AMultitouchDriver 3440.1
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3440.8
>!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    7.0.4f6
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.4f6
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    5.1.16
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.4.5
|IOGraphics!F   575.1
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
>!AThunderboltEDMSink   4.2.3
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  6.2.6
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    840.3
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
@kext.triggers  1.0
>!UMergeNub 900.4.2
>usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.!UHub  1.2
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>!ABCMWLANCore  1.0.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
|IO80211!FV2    1200.12.2b1
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
|IOSurface  269.11
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
>!AXsanScheme   3
>usb.!UVHCIBCE  1.2
>usb.!UVHCI 1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommonBCE    1.0
>usb.!UVHCICommon   1.0
>!AEffaceableNOR    1.0
|IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0
|IOBufferCopyEngine!F   1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.6
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.0
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.101.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.101.1
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
|IOTimeSync!F   840.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 7.0.4f6
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.4f6
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.101.3
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.101.1
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
@kec.Libm   1```

Can anyone make sense of any of this?

Thanks
````

Comment: What have you already tried to fix the problem?

Comment: have no clue where to start tbh, ran disk utility in recovery mode, reset NVRAM, but same things keeps happening

Comment: It would be good to add what you've done to the question (instead of a comment).  That way people won't suggest you do things you've already tried.

Comment: @AndrewJonathan Have a look at my solution at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/390620/macos-catalina-watchdog-timeout-kernel-panics. This fixed it for me. I'm also seeing a lot of people having kernel panics because of Dropbox.